# Assemble n^3 cubes into n different n×n×n larger cubes

Tags: logical-deduction, geometry, three-dimensional

You might have seen [this question](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/77921/color-the-cubes-then-assemble-them-to-form-a-larger-cube) before:

> Goal: Paint 27 cubes using three colors (for example, red, yellow, and blue), so that you can form a 3x3x3 cube with all surfaces in red (for example), a 3x3x3 cube all in yellow, and a 3x3x3 cube all in blue by rearranging the painted cubes, not repainting them.

Let's generalize this to $n\times n\times n$ cubes with $n$ colors! (Note that this is the same $n$.)

### Duplicate

The linked question already has an answer for the general case: https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/77926/85500

### Detailed problem statement

You have $n^3$ equally-sized small cubes; let's call them "cubelets". Also, you have $n$ paint buckets with different colors.

You can paint all of the faces of all cubelets with one color each. You can color each of the 6 faces of each cubelet individually, but each face has to be unicolored.

Because there are exactly $n^3$ cubelets, you can then arrange them into a big $n\times n\times n$ cube. Note that each set of cubelets can be arranged in multiple ways.

When arranging the cubelets, some of the cubelet faces will be visible on the assembled cube, facing outside, and some will be internal, touching a face of another cubelet. For some arrangements of some colorings, all the visible faces will have the same color.

The question is to find a coloring of the $n^3$ cubelets such that, for each of the $n$ colors, there is an arrangement of the cubelets where only that color is visible on the outside.

For example, for $n=4$, the colors might be red, green, blue, yellow. Then, color a set of $4^3=64$ cubelets, such that this single set can be arranged into four different $4\times 4\times 4$ cubes, where one of the arrangements shows only red, one only green, one only blue, and one only yellow.

For which $n$ (starting from $n=1$) is this possible? If possible, give an example coloring; if impossible, prove why.

### Hints

> $n=1$ and $n=2$ are both possible, with a very simple and unique solution each.

> $n=3$ is also pretty simple.

> $n=4$ and $n=5$ are harder than $n=3$ and $n=6$. (Or rather, were harder for me personally.)

> There is a pretty nice solution of $n=6$ which can be used for $n>6$ as well.

> Do some combinatorics: How many visible cubelet faces does one arrangement have? When considering that you need $n$ different arrangement, how many different visible faces do you need in total? And how many faces do you have available in total?

> Think about how many different ways there are to color one cubelet. Which of those are useful and which aren't?

> If you're really stuck, look at the answer of the mentioned post, or watch the video, to get a solution for $n=3$. This might give you an idea how to approach this.

---

<sub>I believe the original source of this puzzle for the $n=3$ case is [this TED-Ed riddle](https://youtu.be/SXXrQlJoNsw); this video is a few months older than the post mentioned above. Spoiler alert: The video contains a solution for $n=3$.</sub>

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Puzzling! Looks like you're off to a good start already! That said, it's customary to wait (a full day at least, so everyone gets a go at the puzzle regardless of their timezone) before dropping extra hints.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know that, sorry. Should I remove the hints or leave them, because some people might already have seen them?

Comment: Well, they are now part of the question, so it's better not to try and hide them anymore. (The edit history would still show them.) And these hints don't really give all that much away anyway, so no worries :-)

Comment: An answer for the general case was provided in response to the linked question.

Comment: Yes, [my answer](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/77926/20814) to the linked question is a general one, so that actually makes this question a duplicate, sorry.

Comment: Ah, whoops, I missed that...